# How to setup a second wifi access point and set static IP

Tags: windows, networking, router, ip, wireless-access-point

```
+-----------------+            +----------------+
|   Laptop        |            |  Router 1      |
|                 |----Wifi----|  with internet |
|    Windows 10   |            |  connection    |
|                 |            +----------------+
|                 |
|                 |            +----------------+
|                 |--Ethernet--|Router2 AP mode |
+-----------------+            |                |
                               |                |
                               +----------------+
```

Hi people!
I'm trying to setup a second AP for my VR headset to stream games from Windows PC (steamVR) to the VR headset(Pico 4).
UPD. The second router model is **ASUS RT-AX55**. I chose this model because it has been proved as working solution for the VR streaming. Also I haven't configure it any way.

My goals are:

1. Set static IP to the 2nd router in order to be able to enter the admin page.
2. Share the Internet to the 2nd router from the first wifi connection.
   UPD: I use Pico 4 VR headset and it works in 2 modes:
   a. **Standalone** - when you need the internet to log in into your
   account(you can do nothing without registrations nowadays).
   b. **Virtual desktop mode** - when games run on the PC and go into VR headset via wifi.

I use 1st router for the Internet, it's connected to my PC via wifi(as on the ASCII image).
Also I connected the 2nd router via ethernet cable to the PC. I use one of the LAN ports on the router.

The problem is that I get ***"unidentified network"*** in the status of connection, and something like:

```
DHCP Enabled: Yes
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address: 169.254.80.141
IPv4 Default Gateway:
```

These results happen only in "obtain an IP address automatically" mode.

My **1st** wifi router has 192.168.0.1  gateway address, and **I have** an access to the admin page.

Question is - how to setup IP for the 2nd router? Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear why you want to connect the 2nd router to your laptop. Can't you connect it directly to your 1st router? That should give router 2 internet access from router 1.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Why do you want to share the internet connection when your goal is to "stream games from Windows PC (steamVR) to the VR headset"? What model is Router2 and how is it configured?

Comment: Your picture is not clear. You do not need two NICs inside your workstation. You should be able to set up the Wireless Router to the main Router LAN to LAN and DCHP OFF.  I always give the second router a static IP on the main network.

Comment: I know, that router to router setup should be the easiest way, but as I described, the milliseconds latency are critical. for example, I tried to connect my headset directly to the 1st router, and it didn't go well, the picture was freezing easch second.

Comment: So in case you are wondering why we are so unkeen on your design, is that the NIC that a PC uses to communicate with a destination is determined by IP Routing tables, which specify that to get to a given network, you go out a particular NIC. in this case however, your laptop is connected to the same network via two NICs, and only one of them can be used at runtime. so you either need two networks, one for each nic, or you need to send all your traffic for 190.168.0.0/24 over ethernet, and all traffic to 0.0.0.0 (the internet) over the wifi via gateway 192.168.0.1

Comment: Is the only purpose of Router 2 the connection to your VR headset? Does the VR headset need internet connection or only a connection to the Laptop? Is the VR headset connected to Router 2 via WiFi? Does the program that wants to send data to the VR headset try to detect the headset's address automatically or do you configure the address manually? In theory you could configure Router 2 in Wireless router mode to provide a network different from Router 1's network, e.g `192.168.x.*` where `x != 0` for both ethernet LAN and WiFi including DHCP and leave the WAN/Internet port open.

Comment: Does the VR headset need internet connection or only a connection to the Laptop? - Yes, it needs Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

In your original configuration, you showed your PC connected to Router 1 (R1) via WIFI, as well as Router 2 (R2) via ethernet.

In your [comment](https://superuser.com/users/1770807/spacewormsera) you noted:

> *in order to make the latency as low as possible, it's recommended to connect AP directly to the PC via ethernet*

This leads me to believe that R2 is connected to R1 via WIFI.  I have however shown both possibilities below.

#### What you have right now

```
# Either, Possibility 1:

+--------+            +---------------------+
| Win PC |----WIFI----| Router 1 (Internet) |
+--------+            +---------------------+
     |                         |
     |                       WIFI
     |                         |
     |                +------------------+
     +----Ethernet----| Router 2 AP mode |
                      +------------------+


# Or, Possibility 2:

+--------+            +---------------------+
| Win PC |----WIFI----| Router 1 (Internet) |
+--------+            +---------------------+
     |                         |
     |                      Ethernet
     |                         |
     |                +------------------+
     +----Ethernet----| Router 2 AP mode |
                      +------------------+
```

##### What you need

Further to the same [comment](https://superuser.com/users/1770807/spacewormsera) referencing ***latency*** and connecting ***directly*** to the PC you should note that if R2 cannot connect directly to R1 then you are still introducing latency between R1 and PC even though you are minimizing it between R2 and your PC.

If latency is a concern you want to be connected via ethernet **directly to R1** or **directly to R2 which is connected directly to R1**.

If you cannot connect R2 via ethernet to R1, you should try to connect via WIFI from PC to R1 and skip R2.  Using 5GHz between PC and R1 if possible may provide better performance if you are encountering interference on the 2.4GHz spectrum.

```
# Either, Option 1

+--------+            +---------------------+
| Win PC |            | Router 1 (Internet) |
+--------+            +---------------------+
     |                         |
     |                     Ethernet
     |                         |
     |                +------------------+
     +----Ethernet----| Router 2 AP mode |
                      +------------------+


# Or, Option 2

+--------+            +---------------------+
| Win PC |--Ethernet--| Router 1 (Internet) |
+--------+            +---------------------+


# Or, Option 3

+--------+            +---------------------+
| Win PC |----WIFI----| Router 1 (Internet) |
+--------+            +---------------------+
```

##### Router 1

- DHCP Server enabled
- WIFI<sup>*</sup> SSID(s) and channel(s) different from Router 2

##### Router 2

- DHCP disabled
- IP in the same Subnet as Router 1
- WIFI<sup>*</sup> SSID(s) and channel(s) different from Router 1

***** While you likely need 2.4GHz on at least one of your Routers.  If it isn't needed on the other, disable it. If you are lucky enough to be running no 2.4GHz clients, disable it on both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but here comes a problem: in order to make the latency as low as possible, it's recommended to connect AP directly to the PC via ethernet, otherwise I loose time on the 1st router.  Can I actually keep the connections as I already described?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  You can do what you prefer, my goal is only to give you good advice.  The latency is between R1 and PC so if you need to introduce a WIFI connection (should be avoided if direct connection is the goal) it should be between PC and R1 (if possible)